# Could not find method android()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Error log:

> ERROR: Could not find method android() for arguments
>   [build_szu6u1qudhn719nxb58vfd0f$_run_closure1@1fcc37a7] on root
>   project 'prueva2'.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.MyApp'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google() // For Gradle 4.0+
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip
```

What could be the issue for this, any solution?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: I saw it, but I don't know what to change

Comment: You shouldn't just see it. You should read it carefully, and look at the examples.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up project configuration from the top-level build.gradle with module configuration from a module-level build.gradle. The android stuff goes to module level only, and you need to apply the android plugin. Also, gradle 2.6 is very old, consider using a newer version like 5.6.4.

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip*** 
still the same

Comment: ERROR: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_szu6u1qudhn719nxb58vfd0f$_run_closure1@46547412] on root project 'prueva2'.

Comment: do you have separate Project-level build.gradle file ?   

allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven
        }
    }
usually appears in Project-level dependency - not in Module-level dependency

Comment: No, but I leave it for 2 days and nothing, thanks